# To apply less than condition in delete query on the value obtained from select clause

Tags: sql-server

I want to compare two table T1 and T2 and delete records from T1 which has form_no less than the form_no selected form T2.
I have written following query, but it is not working.

```
DELETE FROM T1
WHERE --Some Condition--
AND
FORM_NO < (ISNULL((SELECT DISTINCT(FORM_NO) FROM T2 WHERE --Some Condition--), 0))
```

Comment: depends on your where condition. You need to ensure your select query returns only one record value.

Comment: Its returning only one value but still its not working.

Comment: Why don't you do the comparison and return all `FORM_NO` within a subquery. Then take the results as an array of `FORM_NO` to do the delete with `IN` - as per my answer. Please comment if you need otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one... wish you could provide us the full query though..

```
DELETE FROM T1
WHERE --Some Condition--
AND FORM_NO IN (SELECT DISTINCT(t.FORM_NO) FROM T1 AS t
        LEFT JOIN T2 AS s
        ON -- COMMON COLUMN
        WHERE t.FORM_NO < s.FORM_NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you have an common field and want to delete joining on this field:

```
delete from t11 
    from t1 t11
        join t2 on (t11.commonID=t2.commonID)
    where (t11.FORM_NO<t2.FORM_NO)
```

If you want exactly what you ask so:

```
delete from t1 where FORM_NO<(select min(FORM_NO) from t2)
```